# OAuth 2.0 Flow: Server-side web apps- error : missing: grant_type

Tags: curl, google-oauth

I got the following errr when trying to follow example 
[OAuth 2.0 Flow: Client-side web apps](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -F 'client_id=739532980462-7ra1v7rqn798u4j0dcgvh45joo5dma9e.apps.googleusercontent.com'  -F 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:18080/examples' -F  'response_type=token' https://accounts.google.com//o/oauth2/token                 {
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" 
}
```

I have followed the example but I am getting error message:

> error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

What can be wrong with my query or setup ?

Regards,
Oliver

Comment: Are you sure the uri suffix is `oauth2/token` rather than `oauth2/auth` they mention in their docs?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter above mentioned you should be using:

```
curl ... https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
```

instead of:

```
curl ... https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```